# How to display text in html format in GridView generated from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a method to create a DataTable:

```
private DataTable GetCssPropertiesDataTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    DataColumn column;
    DataRow row;

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = typeof(string);
    column.ColumnName = "Property";
    column.Caption = "Property";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = typeof(double);
    column.ColumnName = "Value";
    column.Caption = "Value";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = typeof(string);
    column.ColumnName = "Unit";
    column.Caption = "Unit";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(column);

    row = dataTable.NewRow();
    row["Property"] = "A";
    row["Value"] = A;
    row["Unit"] = "m<sup>2</sup>";
    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

    return dataTable;
}
```

a gridview (aspx):

```
<asp:GridView ID="cssPropertiesGridView" runat="server" CssClass="gridView"></asp:GridView>
```

and databinding in code behing (aspx.cs):

```
cssPropertiesGridView.DataSource = calculator.CssPropertiesDataTable;
cssPropertiesGridView.DataBind();
```

the result on a generated web page:

```
m<sup>2</sup>
```

Is there way how to display **m<sup>2</sup>** ?

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the property HtmlEncode="false" for unit column (in datagrid) like in the following snippet, in order to display html

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Property" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit" HtmlEncode="False" />
</Columns>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how can you do this with the datatable object. something like `datatable.columns[1].htmlEncode= false`?

Comment: Not sure I'm getting your question properly.

A datatable is an object used to store some data in memory.
A gridview is a control which can render data, so in this particular case a datatable configured as datasource.

Now the subject here is how can we handle HTML avoiding the encoding as text? This is something we can do acting on the rendering of the data more than on the data side.

Even assuming you changed the encoding in the datatable (or even in your source, database, file, service...), that wouldn't prevent the gridview from encoding once the databind is performed.